# Iterative as a trait with Traversable

Tags: php

I want to create PHP's Iterators using my trait named Iterative. I tried to do this in this way:

1. Trait Iterative "implements" interface Traversable

   ```
    trait Iterative
    {
        public function rewind(){ /* ... */ }
        public function current(){ /* ... */ }
        public function key(){ /* ... */  }
        public function next(){ /* ... */ }
        public function valid(){ /* ... */ }
    }
   ```
2. Class BasicIterator should implement the interface using trait

   ```
    class BasicIterator implements \Traversable {
        use Iterative;
    }
   ```

but i get:

```
    Fatal error: Class BasicIterator must implement interface Traversable as part of either Iterator or IteratorAggregate in Unknown on line 0
```

Is it even possible and in what way?

Comment: I don't think you can use the Traversable interface like that.  http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with using Traits, but because you are implementing the wrong interface. See this note on [the manual page for Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php):

> This is an internal engine interface which cannot be implemented in PHP scripts. Either IteratorAggregate or Iterator must be used instead.

Write `class BasicIterator implements \Iterator` instead, since [that is the interface whose methods you have included in your Trait](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you must implement either Iterator, or IteratorAggregate, eg:

```
<?php
trait Iterative
{
    public function rewind(){ /* ... */ }
    public function current(){ /* ... */ }
    public function key(){ /* ... */  }
    public function next(){ /* ... */ }
    public function valid(){ /* ... */ }
}

# Class BasicIterator should implements the interface using trait

class BasicIterator implements \Iterator {
    use Iterative;
}
?>
```

see http://3v4l.org/G7KiF